# FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I don't seem to be able to find the libRCTFBSDK.a file:

[image]

So I get the error:

> FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found

I have most definitely added the frameworks to the frameworks folder, choosing not to copy if needed. And I have definitely added the file paths to `framework search paths` and it is the correct file path:

[image]

In the top image should librctFBSDK be in that list??

Comment: Have the same issue here. I was using these instructions:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started

Also I've been trying to install the lib with using of instructions on github page, but also got no success (with some different errors).

Comment: @andrfas Take a look at my answer. It worked for me. It might not apply to you be best to check. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I believe what solved it for me was upgrading react-native from `0.43` to `0.48`

```
npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
cd MyReactNativeApp
react-native-git-upgrade
```

This introduced other errors that I solved one by one.

Check your react-native version: `react-native -v` if it is quite low like `0.43` then I recommend upgrading it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the new upgrade tool based on Git. It makes upgrades easier by resolving most conflicts automatically.
To use it:

```
- Go back to the old version of React Native
- Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade"
- Run "react-native-git-upgrade"
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html